# how to know the procedure call is completed or not when called from rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, stored-procedures

I need to call a MySQL procedure from rails controller and need to know the procedure call got executed completely or not.How can I expect it.

I am calling the procedure as ActiveRecord::Base.connections.exec_query("call procedureName("abc"))

Thanks in advance

Comment: put `select 1 as success_flag` as last line in your procedure. and get this value in your web app to check procedure end.

Comment: when I call the procedure it is returning the mysql object and not the return value of the procedure.